# Changing physical path to the folder path

Tags: asp.net, path

I am saving Images to my physical path and now I want to change it's path to my server folder named"Uploads" can anyone help me out in this?

```
ingestPath = @"C:\temp\ingest\";
```

I need to change this path to the existing folder on my server and I did this way but it's not working

```
ingestPath="~/Uploads/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/")`

Comment: Thanks for your reply and It's showing error at Server.Actually I'm using jquery blueimp image uploader.

Answer (score 0):

It's not correct to work with absolute address in websites whether in your machine or on the server .

You should work with relative address and as you may know in asp.net '~' character refer to the root of your website . So when you upload a file through the application even in your machine , You need to use  `Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/")` method wich maps the specified relative or virtual path to the corresponding physical directory on the server.